# Map Zoom Issue on move picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, turn

http://demo.globalmedya.com/ilgenvida.com/cevirbak/index.php in this link after click the zoom button if i move the picture somewhere with mouse, i can't stop it always the picture follows the mouse. What should i do? Thx.

and this is mousemove :

```
function() {
  if ($.browser.webkit) {
    $('#page').css('cursor', '-webkit-grabbing');
  }
  if ($.browser.mozilla) {
    $('#page').css('cursor', '-moz-grabbing');
  }
  if ($.browser.msie) {
    $('#page').css('cursor', 'url(../img/closedhand.cur)');
  }
}
```

This is the grabbing code:

```
    book_grabbing: function() { 
      if ($.browser.webkit) { 
             $('#page').css('cursor', '-webkit-grabbing'); 
      }
      if ($.browser.mozilla) {
             $('#page').css('cursor', '-moz-grabbing');
      }
      if ($.browser.msie) {
             $('#page').css('cursor', 'url(../img/closedhand.cur)');
      }
   }
```

Comment: book_grabbing: function() {
  if ($.browser.webkit) {
   $('#page').css('cursor', '-webkit-grabbing');
  }
  if ($.browser.mozilla) {
   $('#page').css('cursor', '-moz-grabbing');
  }
  if ($.browser.msie) {
   $('#page').css('cursor', 'url(../img/closedhand.cur)');
  }
 }

Comment: this is the grabbing code

Comment: I FIXED IT ADDING THIS CODE

Comment: $("#page").click(function(){
   $( this ).removeClass("draggable");
  });